# Problem with Reachability: invalid conversion from 'BOOL' to 'NetworkStatus'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Good morning,

I am trying to use Reachabily libraries and when I try to compile I always obtain the same error:

error: invalid conversion from 'BOOL' to 'NetworkStatus'

This is produced in:

```
BOOL retVal = NotReachable;
if((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) && (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsDirect))
{
    retVal = ReachableViaWiFi;  
}
return retVal;     // error: invalid conversion from 'BOOL' to 'NetworkStatus'
```

I just saw this post : [How to compile specific files in objective-c++ and the rest of the project in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756209/how-to-compile-specific-files-in-objective-c-and-the-rest-of-the-project-in-obj) but it does not work.

I made a new proyect only with this libraries and all works perfect and I think that the problem could be the others linkings flags:
-lstdc++
-all_load

Could you help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should return a `NetworkStatus`. I think your variable `retVal` should not of type `BOOL` but of type `NetworkStatus`. In fact, setting `ReachableViaWiFi` on a `BOOL` could already be considered a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Finally I make a cast it works perfect :)

Comment: @damacri86 Why are you casting and not just setting the variable to be the correct type?

Comment: @damacri86 I highly recommend what @Nick Bull says... make the variable the correct type instead of assigning to a wrong type in the first place.

Comment: Well those are Reachablity libraries and I don't want to change them. They usually works, but I probably have one special flag that is making the problem. Thank you very much :)