# Reference ambiguous to Cocos2d-x Size type

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-x, ambiguous

I want to implement some *objective c* calls in *c++ project* i.e. Am trying to do same thing as "[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756209/how-to-compile-specific-files-in-objective-c-and-the-rest-of-the-project-in-ob/)" (*compile some specific files as objective c++*)

but then i get into "Reference ambigious" errors for this line of code :

```
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
```

saying "**Reference to 'Size' is ambigious**"

my current compiler settings:

```
C Lang Dialect : GNU99[-std=gnu99]
Compiler Sources As : According to File Type

C++ Language Dialect : GNU++14[-std=gnu99]
C++ Standard Library : libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with c++11 support)
```

Comment: Is that all the error message tells you?

Comment: Any file whose suffix is `.mm` will be treated as Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `Size` type exists in Cocos2d-x and somewhere else in the header files the compiler has seen.

Luckily all of Cocos2d-x is defined in its own namespace, so you need to do the following in the offending file(s):

1. Remove `USING_NS_CC` from the top of implementation file.
2. Add the `cocos2d::` namespace to any Cocos2d-x type and class references in the implementation file, for example:

   ```
   cocos2d::Size visibleSize = cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
   ```

That tells the compiler exactly which `Size` type you are referring to.

Also Cocos2d-x supports C++11 but not C++14 as far as I know, so change that in the build settings.

Comment: wow! perfect explanation i needed.

I was stuck on that for few days already. Thanks @trojanfoe !